# How i can print a file with ICU's library?

Tags: c, window, icu

I've tried to open, read, and print my file who contains chiness's char.

```
UChar   tab[50];
UFILE   *file;

if ((file = u_fopen("test.txt", "r", uloc_getDefault(), "UTF-16BE")) == NULL)
    return (fprintf(stderr, "error: fail top open test.txt"));
u_fgets(tab, 100, file);
u_printf("%s\n", tab);
u_fclose(file);
return (0);
```

In output, i've : "]]??"

I don't understand this.
However, i've set my locale's system to chinese, my file is encoding with "UTF-16BE"
PS : I'm coding on a Windows system
Please..it's very important !

Answer (score 0):

It's likely the issue is that you're using an incorrect format specifier. The `%s` format specifier tells `u_printf()` to expect a C-style `char*` string in the variadic argument stream. If you want to pass a UTF-16 `UChar*` string as the argument, you have to use the `%S` specifier. See the documentation at http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ustdio_8h.html, specifically under the section **Formatting and Parsing Specification**.

So change

```
u_printf("%s\n", tab);
```

to

```
u_printf("%S\n", tab);
```